# extracting json data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

uses tmdb api to extract movie information using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',  
        mode = 'search/movie?query=',
        input,
        movieName,
        key = '&api_key=fed63cb1875f494391fd712f9a2aed7e';
```

on button click it calls the api,

```
 $('#submit-btn').click(function() {  
        var input = $('#movie-text').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + mode + input + key,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'testing',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                console.dir(json);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
   var newurl = url + mode + input + key ;
   console.log(newurl);

//giving errors in get 

 $.getJSON(newurl+"?callback=?",function(json){

    console.log(json[0].results[0].original_title); 
//printing the movie title on the ***console*** 

 });
    });
});
```

It gives me follwing ***errors***,

> GET http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=avengers&api_key=fed63cb1875…9a2aed7e?callback=jQuery19104732654287945479_1438057058565&_=1438057058566
>
> b.extend.ajax
>   b.extend.getJSON
>   (anonymous function)
>   b.event.dispatch
>   v.handle
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Use a valid key, the code looks ok

Comment: the key is ok. it is giving error in callback may be

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z7z9ozu1/1/

Comment: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=exodus&api_key=fed63cb1875f494391fd712f9a2aed7e

Comment: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=exodus&api_key=fed63cb1875f494391fd712f9a2aed7e

Comment: change `json[0].results[0].original_title` to `json.results[0].original_title` and remove `"?callback=?"`

Answer (score -1):

You must provide a **`valid key`**.

***`Invalid Key:`***

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=avengers&api_key=fed63cb1875

Please use ***`api_key`*** as follows:

`fed63cb1875f494391fd712f9a2aed7e`

Please check following ***`url`:***

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=avengers&api_key=fed63cb1875f494391fd712f9a2aed7e